# Hamburger menu not showing on mobile phone

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I just finished my homepage, but when it comes to testing I'm a bit confused the navbar is completely fine on my Desktop browser for all sizes, but when i test it on my android phone in any browser the button does not take any effect...

anyone help me please... I've done everything perfectly, I don't know why...
I'm using flowbite

here is the component code :

```js
import Logo from './../assets/aocLogo.png';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='p-3 border-gray-200 bg-gray-800  '>
      <div className='container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto'>
        <a href='#' className='flex items-center'>
          <img src={Logo} className='h-6 mr-3 sm:h-14' alt='AOC Logo' />
        </a>
        <button
          data-collapse-toggle='navbar-solid-bg'
          type='button'
          className='inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-100 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200   '
          aria-controls='navbar-solid-bg'
          aria-expanded='false'
        >
 
         <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
          <svg
            className='w-6 h-6'
            aria-hidden='true'
            fill='currentColor'
            viewBox='0 0 20 20'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
          >
            <path
              fillRule='evenodd'
              d='M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z'
              clipRule='evenodd'
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div className='hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto' id='navbar-solid-bg'>
          <ul className='flex flex-col mt-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-900  md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium md:border-0 md:bg-transparent'>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-100 bg-yellow-500 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-yellow-300 md:p-0'
                aria-current='page'
              >
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                About
              </a>
 
           </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Team
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Events
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you [installed Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/)?

Flowbite uses javascript to remove the `hidden` class from the menu when the button is clicked. If you just copy the HTML+CSS it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't appear is because you passed hidden default and md:block in the menu. This is how to fix it.

```
import Logo from './../assets/aocLogo.png';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='p-3 border-gray-200 bg-gray-800  '>
      <div className='container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto'>
        <a href='#' className='flex items-center'>
          <img src={Logo} className='h-6 mr-3 sm:h-14' alt='AOC Logo' />
        </a>
        <button
          data-collapse-toggle='navbar-solid-bg'
          type='button'
          className='inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-100 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200   '
          aria-controls='navbar-solid-bg'
          aria-expanded='false'
        >
 
         <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
          <svg
            className='w-6 h-6'
            aria-hidden='true'
            fill='currentColor'
            viewBox='0 0 20 20'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
          >
            <path
              fillRule='evenodd'
              d='M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z'
              clipRule='evenodd'
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div className='w-full md:w-auto' id='navbar-solid-bg'>
          <ul className='flex flex-col mt-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-900  md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium md:border-0 md:bg-transparent'>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-100 bg-yellow-500 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-yellow-300 md:p-0'
                aria-current='page'
              >
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                About
              </a>
 
           </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Team
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Events
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                href='#'
                className='block text-base py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-50 rounded hover:bg-yellow-500 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-yellow-400 md:p-0 '
              >
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: I pasted the code but it appears just opened in my phone, the button does not work in 
 smartphone, but in desktop it does

Comment: have you added the js part of the code from Flowbite? or maybe there is some issue with or maybe you have not linked the library properly

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work perfectly fine.

Try this link [Tailwind-css play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GVSysov5tz)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and found a fix that at least worked for me! I was having the same issue with my Navbar Menu Button and Accordion where if you tried to use them on mobile phones, nothing would happen.

Try adding this code to any Flowbite component you can interact with if not working otherwise:

```
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite'

useEffect(() => {
  initFlowbite();
}, []);
```

I found this fix from:

https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/460